# Nested JSON failed to deserialize

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

This is the link for my nested JSON
 : -
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=AIzaSyDk8ZfHO__XrYfDGi9RnFA_WxlVmRW5HMI

i have generated a model class which has to give me the list of names , later i populate them in a RecyclerView.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace newApp.Model
{

    public class Location
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Northeast
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Southwest
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Viewport
    {
        public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
    }

    public class OpeningHours
    {
        public bool open_now { get; set; }
    }

    public class Photo
    {
        public int height { get; set; }
        public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
        public string photo_reference { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
    }

    public class PlusCode
    {
        public string compound_code { get; set; }
        public string global_code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
        public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public PlusCode plus_code { get; set; }
        public double rating { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
        public string vicinity { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then , in this method i tried to deserialize the data , i want to get a list of ***icon, name , id and location***.

This is the method i initially have :

```
 public async  void getData()
        {

            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(URL);

            var n = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Result>>>(content);

            Debug.WriteLine("Output ", n);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to deserialize to the `RootObject` class directly:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

And then retrieve all data you need using LINQ. 
Declare `ResultHeadInfo` class which will contain fields you need:

```
public class ResultHeadInfo
{
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

Then write LINQ query to get data:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

List<ResultHeadInfo> infoList = root.results.Select(x => new ResultHeadInfo {
        Location = x.geometry.location,
        Name = x.name,
        Id = x.id,
        Icon = x.icon
    }).ToList();
```

By the way, you can use just `Location` object instead of `Northest` and `Southwest` as they are identical.

```
public class Viewport
{
    public Location northeast { get; set; }
    public Location southwest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you please try to add for me the linq code to search out the icon, name , id and location. It will be my pleasure

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Comment: hey why .Select having an error , i installed the nuget package but it's showing an error

Comment: using System.Linq;

Comment: sorry my typo, results.results.Select(x => new ResultHeadInfo

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, don't forget you can use attributes to identify the fields but keep the property names consistent with the usual naming conventions:

```
    public partial class Viewport
    {
        [JsonProperty("northeast")]
        public Location Northeast { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("southwest")]
        public Location Southwest { get; set; }
    }
```

I created those same classes recently for my project, and used [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/) to generate them.  Much better output than the usual 'Paste Special' built into VS.